# Сброс к RooViewController'у при повороте экрана

Tags: ios, swift

В проекте расставлены галочки поворота экрана, но мы блокируем поворот экрана почти везде, помимо пару экранов (где отображаем изображение во весь экран).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

путь выглядит так 1 -> `pushFrontViewController` на 2 он открывает 3 (`TableView`) (`title` = главная) -> открываем боковой бар 4 от туда -> 5 он октывает 6(`TableView`)(`title` = фото) тапаем на любой элемент из списка открываем 7 он открывает 8(`CollectionView`), тапаем на любую картинку делаем  present на 9(он у нас может быть и в горизонтальном и в вертикальном режиме). когда на 9 поворачиваем экран, Проблема в том что после тапа в горизонтальном режиме на "X" он нас скидывает на экран 3, что еще очень странно на экране 3 `title` = Фото

при тапе на "X" делаю `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Переходы между экранами осуществляю следующим образом:

```
    let vc: ImageCollectionViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewController") as! ImageCollectionViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

переходы с бокового бара осуществляю следующим образом:

```
vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoNavigationViewController") as? UINavigationController
        let rvc:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController() as SWRevealViewController
        rvc.pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Это потому что я использую либу  `SWReveal` и мне нужно после Тапа с бокового бара отображать бургер.Поэтому этот вариант мне подходит.

Comment: Как реализованы переходы?

Comment: @VAndrJ обновил вопрос.